# Django View Throwing HttpResponseError

Tags: django, view, httprequest

I am simply trying to map a view to a path in `urls.py`, but when I try to it throws this error:

```
Registration didn't return an HttpResponse object
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^Register/$', Registration),
    (r'^Newuser/$', ProcessRegistration),
)
```

**views.py**

```
def Registration(request):
    RegForm = RegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if RegForm.is_valid():
            clearUserName = RegForm.cleaned_data['userNm']   
            clearPass = RegForm.cleaned_data['userPass']
            RegForm.save()
            try:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/Newuser/?userNm=' + clearUserName)
            except:
                raise ValidationError(('Invalid request'), code='300')    ## [ TODO ]: add a custom error page here.
    else:
        RegForm = RegistrationForm()

        return render(request, 'VA/reuse/register.html', {
            'RegForm': RegForm 
        })

def ProcessRegistration(request):
    clearUserName = request.GET.get('userNm')
    return HttpResponse("Wee")
```

When I visit `/Register`, it throws the above error.

Any idea why its not working? It is returning a response of `Wee`

Comment: Wait, is it throwing the above error or a response of Wee? Which is it?

Comment: The above error. It is not throwing "Wee" which it should be, right?

Comment: Not if `RegForm.is_valid()` returns false. If that happens, the function returns nothing, and you get that error.

Comment: Not to mention that `/Newuser/?userNm=...` will never map to `Newuser/$`

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts - figured it out. I will post answer. Thanks David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `validators=[]` for `userNm` was messing it up within my **models.py** . I was up doing:

```
  class Client(models.Model):
        userNm = models.EmailField(verbose_name="Email",max_length=50,unique=True,validators=[RegexValidator('^\w{6,50}$','format: invalid username','Invalid Entry')])
        userPass = models.CharField(verbose_name="Password", max_length=50)
```

I changed the `userNm` declaration to:

```
userNm = models.EmailField(verbose_name="Email",max_length=50,unique=True)
```